# Select From Select Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, query-builder

How can i query this in laravel

```
SELECT * from (SELECT member_services.* FROM `member_services` 
WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2020-04-22' and '2021-04-22') `as member_services WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2020-04-16' and '2020-05-25';`
```

?

Thank you sir. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
$result = DB::select("YOUR MYSQL SELECT QUERY HERE");
```